# Can input audio be processed by more apps at once with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to use the [`QAudioRecorder`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qaudiorecorder.html) to record audio from microphone. My question is, should there be an ongoing Skype call or another application would try to use the microphone, would this result in some error or would both that app and my app receive same audio input data?

Similarly, can I use the `QCamera` and `QMediaRecorder` to access webcam that is being used already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that will work just fine, there won't be any error. Both applications will receive the same audio input data. I tested to record the same thing at the same time using Windows' voice recorder program and a simple Qt program built with the following code, and the result was that both output files were recorded the sound correctly:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QAudioRecorder>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QUrl>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QAudioRecorder *audioRecorder = new QAudioRecorder;

    QAudioEncoderSettings audioSettings;
    audioSettings.setCodec("audio/amr");
    audioSettings.setQuality(QMultimedia::HighQuality);

    audioRecorder->setEncodingSettings(audioSettings);
    audioRecorder->setOutputLocation(QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:\\Users\\dduck\\Desktop\\test.amr"));

    QPushButton b("Start");

    QObject::connect(&b, &QPushButton::clicked, [&](){
        if(b.text() == "Start"){
            audioRecorder->record();
            b.setText("Stop");
        }
        else{
            audioRecorder->stop();
            app.quit();
        }
    });

    b.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

I assume it would also work if you run that program at the same time as Skype.

So yes, input audio can be processed by a Qt program at the same time as it is processed by other programs.